# confused with dual ac/dc adapter

Tags: voltage

[image]can somebody explain me how this works please?
I bought a power adapter that has a dual output stated on it: 6.5V DC and 9V AC. There are 4 wires coming out of it. I can measure 9V DC on two of them but can't find anywhere the 6.5V DC that I actually need.
many thanks!

Comment: It may be an unregulated supply where the output voltage varies somewhat with load, and 6.5V is the nominal output, but the unloaded voltage is higher.  If it was not sold for your intended application it may not be suitable.

Comment: No datasheet? No pictures, no idea

Comment: now there is a picture too.

Comment: Any chance someone meddled with it and accidentally connected one of the 9V AC wires to the 6.5V DC ones? That would have fried the regulator and that's the reason such dual power adaptors are hardly consumer products.

Comment: What do you need 6.5V for?

Answer (score 1):

It is most likely an [unregulated](http://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/blog/unregulated-power-supply.html) supply which uses a mains transformer, rectifier, and filter capacitor to convert AC to DC. 6.5VDC will be the *nominal* voltage at full load (150mA). The voltage waveforms at input and output of the rectifier typically look like this:-

[image]

There are several reasons for the unloaded voltage being so much higher.

1. The filter capacitor charges up to the *peak* voltage of the rectified sine wave, which is 1.4 times the [rms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root_mean_square#RMS_of_common_waveforms) voltage.
2. The rectifier diodes may each drop 1V or more under full load, but closer to 0.5V at very low current. If a bridge rectifier is used then the current goes through 2 diodes in series, so the the total voltage drop could vary by 1V or more.
3. The transformer has leakage inductance and winding resistance, which causes its output voltage to drop under load. Since the rated voltage is for full load, the unloaded voltage will be higher.
4. The mains voltage could vary by 10% or more, and the power supply has to deliver its rated output at *minimum* mains voltage. The transformer reduces voltage by a fixed ratio, so if the mains voltage is higher then the transformer's output voltage will also be higher.

Under load the transformer's output voltage will reduce, the diodes will drop more voltage, and the filter capacitor will partially discharge between peaks of the rectified sine wave. As a result of all these losses, the average DC voltage at rated output current should be close to the rated 6.5VDC. To prove this you need to connect a load which draws ~150mA when measuring the DC output voltage.

If your application requires exactly 6.5V then this power supply may not be suitable. However devices which are designed to work with unregulated supplies can usually handle the higher unloaded voltage.

Comment: really appreciate your detailed answer Bruce, I feel I learned something about electronics today, as I am definitely an amateur. What I don't understand why the adapter is rated to output 2 different voltages (as you can see on the picture), the 9V AC and 6.5V DC. When I measured the + and _ wires I've got 9.6V DC. Is that supposed to be my 6.5V DC that I need? I am afraid that if I connect this to what I need (a wireless phone cradle that asks for 6.5V DC) I'm going to fry it... Maybe I should get a different adapter that has only one output. Thoughts?

Comment: The 9VAC is an independent output that was required for the device it was designed to power. If you only need 6.5VDC then just ignore it (ie. do not connect anything to pins 5 and 6 on the plug). Your wireless phone base probably used an unregulated adapter with similar open-circuit voltage, but perhaps a lower current rating and therefore somewhat lower voltage under load. It's probably safe to use it with your base, but to be 100% sure you would have to compare its output to the original base adapter.

Comment: Do you think it's really a separate winding? It's not far from where the secondary would be, if supplying a bridge and cap filter for the DC of 6.5V. Wall wart transformers are often pretty crappy -- 30% regulation. I'd have guessed it was just tapped off before the bridge. Just wondering what led you to different thoughts.

Comment: It _might_ be the same winding tapped into before the rectifier, but I doubt it because in that case it would be simpler and cheaper to just put the rectifier in the device. To prove it you could measure AC voltage between the two outputs (should be very low if they are truly isolated, somewhere between 4.5V and 9V AC if they aren't), or do a diode test measurement between them (with power off!) which should show open circuit if they are isolated. But it's irrelevant anyway because you don't need the AC output!

Comment: I am ignoring pins 5 and 6 since I'm not measuring anything there anyway. I am getting the 9.6VDC between + and - pins, where I'd expect the 6.5VDC that I need. Nobody messed with the adapter, and it was designed for another phone cradle, just not the one I have. Still unsure whether it's safe to use it.

Comment: If you're not sure then play safe and don't use it. Get the official adapter for your phone instead - just don't be surprised to find it also puts out over 9V unloaded...

Comment: it worked, the phone works well with the new adapter, I believe the whole confusion was because the adapter was unregulated. Thanks so much guys for helping out!